Azure DevOps - Share only specific EPIC (and the children) across team boards
I'm setting up a Team A board in Azure DevOps for a new small project.  This project is within an existing, larger Program B, which means some of the works from Program B's backlog will be carried out by Team A.  We share the same iterations and backlog path.
Is there any way to show only relevant EPICs (and features/stories underneath) in Team A board? In Team setting, when I chose Program B's area path as Team A's path all stories are showing in Team A's backlog. What we want is just those relevant to Team A.
Appreciate your help!
